# comparing mail addresses using adist function in R

Tags: r, string-comparison

I have a list of mail addresses (30,000+), and I'd like to compare it against itself in order to find dissimilarities using `levenshtein distance` method.

So I create 2 csv files containing the same list, and I want to use the `adist` function, but it is not reasonable to use it in a 'simple' way (because basically the output should be a matrix of 30,000 on 30,000):

can someone offer me a suitable way of doing it right? maybe constraining  the output to 3 changes or less (but without equality (changes=0) -because as I mentioned the comparison is against itself)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check the `stringdistmatrix` function in the `stringdist` package. That way you can at least perform this in parallel.

Comment: you can use locality sensitive hashing to avoid computing approx dist between every pair of strings